# Is there a way to get Process Ids of other 3rd party applications in Android...?

Tags: android, process

I have a requirement in my project where in i have to kill process of 3rd party application.

As i know Android can have multiple application running at a time, so can i get all those Process

Ids some how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class will help you to kill processes:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html

This gives you a list of currently running processes:

```
ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

The list contains **ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo** objects which store the pid. You can then kill the processes via

```
Process.killProcess(pid);
```

You need the proper permissions to do that. Android should throw an exception if you try to kill a process without the proper permissions and tell you what permission you need.

Answer (score 0):

check this way if it solves your purpose:

```
 ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
            PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
            packs.get(pos).gids;
            packs.get(pos).sharedUserId;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about all running processes using [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29). Refer following code:

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (RunningAppProcessInfo proc : list) {
        Log.v("Proccess", proc.processName + " : " + proc.pid);
    }
```

Multiple applications can be running in the same process, so it would be better to use `RunninAppProcessInfo.pkgList` over `RunninAppProcessInfo.processName`.